# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jme3.system.JmeDesktopSystem JME3

Tags: java

When I try to simulate my little project, I decided to use jme3 library and browsed the jar file through Configure-> JDK Profiles-> Add Archieve-> JME3-core.jar and ran the project sample code. The code was written in a website and I got the exception as:

```
Mar 25, 2014 10:53:44 AM com.jme3.system.JmeSystem checkDelegate
SEVERE: No JmeSystemDelegate specified, cannot instantiate default JmeDesktopSystem:
{0}
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jme3.system.JmeDesktopSystem
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at com.jme3.system.JmeSystem.checkDelegate(JmeSystem.java:125)
    at com.jme3.system.JmeSystem.showSettingsDialog(JmeSystem.java:96)
    at com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication.start(SimpleApplication.java:129)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jme3.system.JmeSystem.showSettingsDialog(JmeSystem.java:97)
    at com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication.start(SimpleApplication.java:129)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)

Process completed.
```

Is the problem about the native libraries kind of issue which is also need to be dealt with J3D libraries? I mean, do I need to follow some instructions about installing and importing JME3 libraries? If so, can anyone tell me the instructions or where to download the correct .jar file?

Answer (score 0):

find a similar discussion [here](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/forum/topic/problem-with-latest-stable-updates/) ..this might be relevant ...

more on the same http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/forum/topic/latest-jme3-sdk-update-trashed-13-of-my-installations/

Comment: The related topic you refer is not clear and recent.